# AOSP: Mute the microphone only on an application and not on the whole device

Tags: android, microphone, mute

In Android, it is possible to mute the microphone with:

```
AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(boolean mute)
```

However, this method mutes the microphone for the whole device and not just the application.

As an AOSP developer, is it possible to mute the microphone only for an application and not on the whole device. I know it should be possible.